# Index element using setter getter android

Tags: java

This is my jsoup parser to extract soap content

```
doc = Jsoup.parse(getxml,"", Parser.xmlParser());

    Elements taux = doc.select("taux");

    Elements devise = doc.select("devise");
    Elements datecours = doc.select("dateCours");
    Elements libelle = doc.select("libelle");
    Elements quotite = doc.select("quotite");
    Elements fixing = doc.select("fixing");
```

Comment: add the result to an ArrayList, and then you can use the results as arrayList.get(index);

Comment: please show me an example if you can

Comment: my postlist is as follows  ArrayList<convertor_pst> PostList = new ArrayList<convertor_pst>();

Comment: aha, is the web service returning all results at once, if so, you should split the results by their separator: String[] separated = CurrentString.split(" ");

Comment: can you modify your code to show this

Comment: How about the other elements, are they all returned as one large string separated with a white space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you. After getting the elements from the web service, assuming that all of the strings contain a large string with separated values, do the following:

```
String[] deviseSeparated = devise.split(" "); 
String[] datecourSeparated = datecour.split(" "); 
String[] libelSeparated = libel.split(" "); 
String[] quotSeparated = quot.split(" "); 
String[] fixSeparated = fix.split(" ");
```

and after that, assuming that all of the arrays are the same size, just execute this for loop, to initiate the objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < deviseSeparated.length; i++) {
    PostList.add(new convertor_pst(deviseSeparated[i],datecourSeparated[i],libelSeparated[i],quotSeparated[i],fixSeparated[i]));
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?